# How is secrets resolved when using environment variable reference in a Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, inversion-of-control, azure-keyvault

I have an environment variable that references a secret in Azure KeyVault:

```
  {
    "name": "SECRET",
    "value": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyvault_name.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret_name/)",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
```

This is loaded when on Startup.cs in my web api solution:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOptions<Secret>().Configure(o => o.ClearText = Configuration["SECRET"]);

        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

How is the secret resolved? Is it resolved on every option call? Eg everytime it gets injected into my constructor, or is it resolved when the environment variable is resoved and loaded into the `Configuration` object?

Reason why I ask is that every call to the vault costs a tiny bit, but it all adds up.

**UPDATE**

I have added this as an issue on github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44064#event-2855607916

Comment: See this comment from a Azure Docs discussion: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42878#issuecomment-558699005
There seems to be caching involved, so it sounds that the WebApp will only retrieve a secret once from KeyVault (or at least not for every call)

Comment: @silent the last three comments on that thread is from me. I can see it does caching, but you need to restart the app before it resolves something new. That is why I am asking for _when_ it does caching. It is undocumented, and i dont like that. If it is undocumented it means that it can shift. Right now it caches really hard, which I like, but it also mean that it can change to not caching. Or to do fetch the secret every once in a while.

Comment: Haha ok I didn’t realize that :) well if you don’t get an answer there I would suggest to open an Azure support ticket to try to get an official answer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my testing, Azure web app will load data from Azure key vault in two scenarios :

1. You submitted a Application settings modify request to Azure.
2. You restart your Azure Web app.

Your secret will be cached in Azure app service. You can try this scenario : After you add an environment variable that references a secret in Azure KeyVault , create a new version with different value in Azure key vault , you will found that the value in Azure web app will not change : still the old version.

It will not change until you restart your web app or modify your Application settings on portal again.

I also checked metrics of my Azure key vault, I called my Azure web app to retrieve the secret I configed in app settings for about 10 times , but the access metrics of my Azure key vault at that time point is 0. But when I restart my web app , the access metrics of Azure key vault will increase .

Hope it helps .

Comment: I have also done this test. Actually I have tested in on two different resource groups, with two different webapps. One gets references from environment variable, and is using docker. The other has a SecretClient and retrieves it directly on each API call. I can see that the SecretClient fetches on every load, and the environment variable uses some sort of cache, as you describe. What I can't find anything about is: how is it cached, and where. If it is not in the official documentation, it can change, and I dont want to see a cost rising because of I thought that it was cached.

Comment: Hi @mslot , I see, to tell the truth , I can not find any docs about that too , that's why I did this test before . As @ silent said ,  if you want to know the details about it , you should raise a support ticket to Azure support team from Azure portal , they can contact product team for more information . Of course , pls mark it as an answer if my answer is helpful :  )

Comment: I have: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44064#event-2855607916 :) Lets hope they will enlighten us!

Comment: @mslot Great ! Let's see how they reply !

Comment: @mslot Have you got the answer that you were looking for?  As Jeff indicates: secrets are loaded into app container environment variables when app startups.

Comment: It looks like the secrets is loaded when the function is started: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44064#issuecomment-567164221

Comment: Hi @mslot , yes, our assumptions were right! Secrets will be loaded into Azure app service(Azure function is based on Azure app service)when it startup and restart phase, it will access Azure KV just once time. pls kindly mark me so that it will asssist others who has similar confusions : )